# Error in extracting json response properties of hydra:collection using RestAssured Java

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm extracting MailTM GET /domains API properties and need to extract the `hydra:member` from the following API response.

```
{
"@context": "/contexts/Domain",
"@id": "/domains",
"@type": "hydra:Collection",
"hydra:member": [
    {
        "@id": "/domains/63d9a7067f7658e92f217bdd",
        "@type": "Domain",
        "id": "63d9a7067f7658e92f217bdd",
        "domain": "eurokool.com",
        "isActive": true,
        "isPrivate": false,
        "createdAt": "2023-02-01T00:00:00+00:00",
        "updatedAt": "2023-02-01T00:00:00+00:00"
    }
],
"hydra:totalItems": 1
```

}

I used JsonPath to extract the values from the response.

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "https://api.mail.tm";

    Response response = given()
                    .when()
                    .get("/domains")
                    .then()
                    .extract().response();  
      
    response.body().jsonPath().get("hydra:member");
```

I can extract the other properties using JsonPath like `@context`, `@type`. But when I'm extracting the `hydra:member`, I'm getting the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the key inside single quote `''`

```java
response.body().jsonPath().get("'hydra:member'");
```